# how can I insert important master table records , if not record exist while running the application

Tags: asp.net-core, dbcontext

How  to insert the  record automatically into the master tables while running the application only if there is no record exist.  At the moment I am doing on model creating in the context class but it doesnot 
 works ,  it only works while running database migration time.  I want to fill the record into master table for necessary drop down list .the record should be inserted only if there is no any record exist on the table VehicleStatus,VehicleType. please help. At the moment my code is as given below

```
public VehicleDBContext(DbContextOptions<VehicleDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Vehicles> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VehicleStatus> VehicleStatus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VehicleType> VehicleType { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<VehicleStatus>()
            .HasData(new
            {
                Id = 1,
                Status = "Active"
            }, new
            {
                Id = 2,
                Status = "Sold"
            }, new
            {
                Id = 3,
                Status = "Scrapped"
            });


        builder.Entity<VehicleType>()
            .HasData(new
            {
                Id = 1,
                Category = "Car"

            }, new
            {
                Id = 2,
                Category = "Van"
            }, new
            {
                Id = 3,
                Category = "SUV"
            });
    }
```

Comment: I am a little confused, don’t you do the migration before running the project?

Comment: I sorted that problem by adding the insert record from program.cs rather than dbcontext. Many Thanks